# Behat not working with the simplest of tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, behat, mink

I'm using Behat with Mink to black box test my application. I've got a *decent* idea of how Behat works, but currently I can't even get one test to successfully work. Here's a picture of what's happening.

Here's an image of my homepage
[image: Homepage]

As you can see, there is clearly a text element that says "hello". This is simply a heading. Now in Behat, I have a test to ensure that I'm at the homepage, which looks for this text element:

[image: Behat Homepage Test]

Here's what I get when I run the test:

[image: Terminal test]

Honestly, I'm stuck and incredibly frustrated. Here's a look at my Behat.yml file

[image: Behat.yml file]

Any help would be SUPER appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant part of a Behat.yml file for a large app I work on with 500+ tests:

```
extensions:
    Laracasts\Behat\ServiceContainer\BehatExtension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension\ServiceContainer\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://localhost:8000
      default_session: laravel
      laravel: ~
```

I'm not sure if it will help you because the rest of our Behat.yml file is kind of hacky for housing different test suites and Selenium...But it's worth a shot.  Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for an element, if you are on the page and you can see it when it fails then maybe is not a text or maybe you have an iframe element and the text is in the iframe.
Inspect the page and search for iframe.

If you have an iframe then you have to switch to iframe first.

Another thing you can do is to get the exact text from page source and see if is the same, maybe the step used is case sensitive and your text is changed by css.